# How to fix all the widgets not show up in the page

Tags: wordpress, filter, widget, themes, sidebar

I added some widgets on the sidebar, and it can show up when I customizing, but still looks like not normal like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R2aA.png), the filter shows up appearance so weird, and when I check it out on the page after published, and it shows up [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n6GH.png), and I inspect the element, and its HTML shows up like that

```
<div class="widget-area secondary" id="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
    <div class="sidebar-main">
        
        
    </div><!-- .sidebar-main -->
</div>
```

Could u please help me, I have been use almost 5 days to figure out this thing, and I really need your help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: I have cleared the site cache now, but the widget still not display.